# hasOwnProperty бросает ReferenceError

Tags: fetch

С помощью fetch делаю GET запрос:

```
fetch("/?mode=ajax&action=gen")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {

           console.log(data);
           console.log(typeof data);

           if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty(added_logs)) {
               throw new Error("Нет логов: поля 'added_logs' в результирующем наборе не найдено!");
           }

           })
      .catch(err => {
            $('#ajax_err span').html(err);
            $('#ajax_err').show();
      })
;
```

data имеет вид:

```
{result: "ok", added_logs: Array(24), added_count: 24}
```

и выводит в консоль object
Но вот участок кода:

```
   if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty(added_logs)) {
       throw new Error("Нет логов: поля 'added_logs' в результирующем наборе не найдено!");
   }
```

бросает ошибку:

```
ReferenceError: added_logs is not defined
```

Не могу понять почему? Ведь свойство added_logs есть в объекте data
Так проверять неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыл про кавычки

```
if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty("added_logs")) {
    throw new Error("Нет логов: поля 'added_logs' в результирующем наборе не найдено!");
}
```

[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)